# Model View Controller Confusion

Tags: java, model-view-controller, model

I have a question about model view controller design pattern.

I am going to explain my thoughts about my question.

if in my model I have an **interface** called **iModel**. I have two classes which implements iModel. First class is called **Game1** and second class called **Game2**

In my view package, I have a Gui class which takes in an iModel instance and makes a game using iModel instance. e.g GUI(iModel m)

Since I pass in iModel, I can pass in two different games but one at a time.

One game

```
iModel m = new Game1();
```

In view, Gui(m) will create Game1

Other game

```
iModel m2 = new Game2();
```

In view, Gui(m2) will create Game2

Now this concept is basically I am passing in multiple models(only one at a time) into the view. The view is just going to be the same but with different data depending on the game(model) chosen.

Now my question is, is that MVC? I read some stuff about MVC is about sending in a model to create all different types of view for that model, but my thoughts are,if passing in different models into the view with the view just the same. Does that count as MVC?

Thanks

Comment: this is not MVC, this is bridge pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now my question is, is that MVC?

From a purely technical stand point, no, because you don't actually have a separate controller, but it is a step in the right direction ;)

> I read some stuff about MVC is about sending in a model to create all different types of view for that model, but my thoughts are,if passing in different models into the view with the view just the same. Does that count as MVC?

That's correct, but I think you might misunderstand what it's saying.  The model doesn't care about the view, it doesn't care how the data is represented, it only cares about up-holding the contract (specified by the `interface`) that the views expect.

Equally, the views don't care about how the models are implemented, only that the models up-hold the contract of the `interface`.

This means that a model might be used by multiple different views that represent the data differently.  Equally, it might be visualised by only one.  The point is, the model shouldn't care.

So I would say your point of view is okay.  A view can represent multiple models over it's life time

Remember, the point of something like the MVC paradigm is to clearly separate and define responsibility between the layers and to decouple the relationships between the layers.

#### Food for thought...

In iOS development, there is a clear separation of the model and view, to the point that neither should interact with each other, in fact, all the communication between them is handled by the controller.  This can sometimes seem at odds, as you want the model to tell the view to update something.

By allowing the controller in this case to act as a proxy or delegate between the model and the view, you actually further decouple the relationship, as you can slide in a new controller which might have it's own view and provide functionality to plugin in view, the point is, you just shouldn't care.

Just so you are completely confused now ;)

Comment: Nice answer. I forgot to include the controller in my example haha, but yea I have already worked with a small example of MVC in a group project. So I have a good idea how controller communicates with the view and model. Just I have never seen multiple models passed in like that before. Your answer explained a lot thanks. I feel more confident now!

Comment: model is the logic representation of the problem space, view is the visual representation of the problem space. They represent the problem space in different perspectives. Controller is the link between model and view. It translates the logical representation to visual representation. At highlevel, we say it handles the interaction between views and models